# VisualStudio Not Recognized in Using Statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I am trying to reference a DLL for unit testing in visual studio.  I added the reference, then added the using statement, but the reference isn't being recognized (See image below).  I get an error stating "The type or namespace name 'Visual Studio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing and assembly reference?)".  I searched other posts with similar issues and a common solution was changing the target framework.  I can't tell if I am having that issue or not.  The target framework is currently set to .NET Framework 4.6.1  I tried setting it to framework 4 because I saw that as a solution in a couple posts, but it didn't change anything. Any ideas why the reference is not being recognized?

[image: Screen Shot of Ref and Using Statement]

Comment: Clean / rebuild / restart VS?

Comment: Are you using express version of visual studio?

Comment: Is the application actually running? i mean can you build it and run it

Comment: I have restarted VS and the reference is still not being recognized.  I am using VS 2017 Community Addition.  The application is not running.  It does not build and run.